# Magento 2.4 error when try to install sample data

Tags: installation, composer, sample-data, magento2.4

I've installed Magento 2.4 (fresh) with the Composer.

Installation work fine (frontend and admin)

But when try to install demo data using [manual](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-composer.html) get an error.

```
$ magento deploy:mode:show         
Current application mode: developer. (Note: Environment variables may override this value.)

$ magento sampledata:deploy
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 20 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing magento/module-catalog-sample-data (100.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing magento/module-bundle-sample-data (100.4.0): Loading from cache
...
- Installing magento/sample-data-media (100.4.0): Loading from cache
<warning>Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.</warning>
<warning>Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.</warning>
<warning>Package sebastian/finder-facade is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.</warning>
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
PHP CodeSniffer Config installed_paths set to ../../phpcompatibility/php-compatibility,../../magento/magento-coding-standard                        

$ magento setup:upgrade    
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
/home/aesa/demo/magento/generated/code/Composer
/home/aesa/demo/magento/generated/code/Dotdigitalgroup
/home/aesa/demo/magento/generated/code/Magento
...
The directory '/home/aesa/demo/magento/generated/metadata/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Magento_AdminAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_Store':
...

Module 'Magento_GroupedCatalogInventory':
Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':
Module 'Magento_CatalogSampleData':
Unable to apply data patch Magento\CatalogSampleData\Setup\Patch\Data\InstallCatalogSampleData for module Magento_CatalogSampleData. Original exception message: Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like it can be related to Composer cache or your `compose.json`.
Try to follow these steps below to install it. In the code below I'll:

- Get the Magento 2.4 via composer
- Install it via CLI with sample data
- Update Composer dependencies
- Compile it

```
# Get Magento 2.4
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com magento/project-community-edition=2.4.0 m24
cd m24

# Install it with sample data
php bin/magento setup:install 
--backend-frontname="admin" 
--session-save="files" 
--db-host="127.0.0.1:9200" 
--db-name="magento24" 
--db-user="root" 
--db-password="admin123" 
--base-url="https://local.m24.com/" 
--base-url-secure="https://local.m24.com/" 
--admin-user="admin" 
--admin-password="admin123" 
--admin-email="admin@admin.com" 
--admin-firstname="Rafael" 
--admin-lastname="Gomes"
--elasticsearch-host=elasticsearch
--use-sample-data 
--cleanup-database

# Update Composer
composer clear-cache
composer update -vvv

# Compile
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento index:reindex
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: --db-host="127.0.0.1:9200" ?? db-host is for mysql not for elasticsearch. Not more dfirrent that my cli command. Exception --use-sample-data and  --session-save="files" and correct values for elasticsearch securized via proxy instead 9200.

Comment: A lot of thanks. With changes on my own line for cli install, work fine.

Comment: --use-sample-data is not parte of doc in https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html#instgde-install-cli-magento

Comment: Sorry but not work. I forget execute magento sampledata:deploy and after magento setup:upgrade. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Check for log in var/log/debug.log . There should be error message.

For me the error was due to problem in saving product. I tried saving product from admin panel but could not. I scheduled update the index and the admin panel product save worked and also the sample data deploy.